# Over loading data while preserving original data in php / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to be able to standardize size and colour information for products. This is because some of our products can come from two or more suppliers ( but its the exact same product ) but they all have their own idea about size and colour names!

In my first attempt I allowed the site admins to simply overwrite the original data to standardize it across supplier. This caused me problems at catalogue update time though, as I had lost the sizes and colour names that had come from each supplier.

I was thinking about using another set of tables to store the standardized data in - for instance, using a standard set of sizes like S,M,L,XL, using another table to map the size id ( row number ) back to multiple variations of size from the supplier data. That would preserve the original data so that I could update it automatically. But it would mean that the mapping table gets very big, very quickly and I was concerned about the performance of having to query this external size table and effectively 'rewrite' the sizes.

At present I cant think of another way to do it while still keeping the original data intact - have I missed a trick or is this the only way?

Here is a basic idea of how I was seeing the over load working

**product_table**:
id
product_id
colour
size
supplier
price

**size_table**:
id
size

**size_map**:
id
size_id
map_to_size ( the data to overload from the product_table )

As previously stated - there is a one to many relationship between the size_table row and which sizes it is meant to replace as laid out in size_map. An example of the data ( basic )

Product: tee-shirt

Supplier A size: 8-10, 11-12, 13-14, 15-16
Supplier B size: S, M, L, XL
Supplier C size: Y/S, Y/M, Y/L, Y/XL

We just want to be able to see S, M, L, XL but have that data revert to the suppliers original for updates and purchase orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**product_table**: id product_id colour standard_size supplier price

**size_map**: id supplier standard_size supplier_size

Comment: That would work - but a colleague suggested simply adding the data as two additional columns to the product_table - it sounds like it would be the fastest option! I'm going to give both your method and the additional column method and see which one is easier to work with / faster!

Once I have a result I will either accept your answer or post a new one underneath. 

For what its worth: My first idea would work but would be large, yours would work and would be smaller but the last seems to be the smallest so far!

Comment: OK - I was right, the addition of columns was the fastest with the smallest footprint ... but not necessarily the correct answer!!

I am going to mark your answer as correct as it is the correct way of doing things ( ie: normalized tables ) - and I would recommend others used the above way too! But for speeds sake and ease of implementation I am just going to extend the table with an additional column!